# Mocking IOrderedQueryable and IDocumentQuery

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, azure-cosmosdb, linq-expressions

I'm using `IDocumentClient` to retrieve and update items in a DocumentDB collection.

The code for retrieving a list of documents that match a condition looks like this:

```
public static async Task<FeedResponse<T>> GetDocuments<T>(
            this IDocumentClient client,
            string collection,
            Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
        {
            IDocumentQuery<T> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(GetCollectionUri(collection)).Where(filter)
                                            .AsDocumentQuery();
            return await query.ExecuteNextAsync<T>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

In order to unit test the code above against a list of mock items, I've created a mock class:

```
public class MockIOrderedQueryable<T> : List<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>, IDocumentQuery<T>
    {
        public Expression Expression
        {
            get
            {
                var content = this.ToList();
                return content.AsQueryable().Expression;
            }
        }

        public IQueryProvider Provider => new MyProvider<T>(this.ToList());

        public Task<FeedResponse<TResult>> ExecuteNextAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken())
        {
            var tmp = new FeedResponse<TResult>((IEnumerable<TResult>)this);
            return Task.FromResult(tmp);
        }    
    }
```

The `Where` filter is an extension method on `IQueryable<T>`, so I needed an implementation that looks like this:

```
public class MyQueryable<T> : IQueryable<T>, IDocumentQuery<T>
    {
        private readonly List<T> _list;

        public MyQueryable(List<T> list)
        {
            _list = list;
        }

        public Task<FeedResponse<TResult>> ExecuteNextAsync<TResult>(CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken())
        {
            var tmp = new FeedResponse<TResult>(_list as List<TResult>);
            return Task.FromResult(tmp);            
        }    
    }
```

And also an implementation of `IQueryProvider` that returns the `IQueryable` instance to my original mock class via `CreateQuery`:

```
public class MyProvider<T> : IQueryProvider
    {
        private readonly List<T> _list;

        public MyProvider(List<T> list)
        {
            _list = list;
        }

        public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
        {
            return new MyQueryable<TElement>(_list as List<TElement>);
        }        
    }
```

For brevity, I omitted the code for the methods that throw `NotImplementedException` and also for the fields that are not used.

This all looks fine, but there's one thing I did not manage to do: applying the real filtering passed as `Expression` in `CreateQuery` on the `_list` member of `MyProvider`. I tried calling `Invoke` and retrieving the arguments, but it did not work. The expression returned in `MockIOrderedQueryable` is probably not the good one (`.AsQueryable` on the list). I'd like to get to a lambda `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` and call it on the list.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I gave a few answers on this topic. Check them out https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A5233410+IDocumentQuery

Comment: Thanks, they are all valuable resources, but my case seems to be a bit different. I'm using Where filter before calling AsDocumentQuery. If I setup the Provider like in the examples you mentioned, I will get a conversion error because the provider has to be an IQueryProvider that returns an implementation of both IQueryable<T>, IDocumentQuery<T>. More than that, I'd like to really evaluate the Expression passed as runtime to the provider instead of a setup in the UT itself. I hope I was clear enough :)